# How to fix spotting caused by spray on acrylic sealer?

Tags: painting, vinyl, sealer

My wife sanded, primed, painted, put vinyl stickers on and then attempted to seal an old coffee table for use in our kid's playroom. Unfortunately, the [Mod Podge Acrylic Sealer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007QNI2U4) caused spotting on the vinyl stickers and painted surface. Is there some way to fix the damage done by the acrylic sealer that doesn't involve starting the project over?

[image: picture of spotting caused by sealer]

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt scuff sand and try again. Its not a for sure fix but it's a zero investment gamble. Just sand it lightly with 220 - 320 (i like these foam backed [sanding pads](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/3MIndustrial/Abrasives/Products/~/3M-Flexible-Foam-Sanding-Sponge?N=7581712%203294240612&rt=rud)) until the spots disappear (hopefully) then clean thoroughly with a tack cloth or micro-fiber cloth and spray it again. If if works great, if not your not out any thing because you would have needed to sand it down and start over anyway. Good Luck!

Comment: This is good advice, spot sand, respray.